# If plutonium-238 (Pu-238) absorbs a neutron, does it become Pu-239?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering, isotopes

I am asking this simple question because I am always hearing about how thorium reactors are less perilous to the world because, unlike uranium reactors, they produce some Pu-238, which is not suitable for a bomb, rather than Pu-239, which is.

But can't Pu-238 be just as easily turned into Pu-239 by absorption of a single neutron, just like U-238 can?

Comment: Indeed that is the main reaction at thermal neutron energies. See ENDF at your favorite host (I usually use Brookhaven).

Comment: Of course, the real question is just how you get to plutonium from the thorium decay chain.

Comment: U-238 can also be "easily" converted to Pu-239 through absorbing a single neutron (and waiting a few days). If you're going to have to add neutrons to it anyway, it's easier to start with U-238, which exists naturally, rather than Pu-238.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, when Pu-238 absorbs a neutron it becomes Pu-239. However, it's *extremely* difficult to separate Pu-238 from Pu-239, much harder than separating U-235 from U-238.

[Pu-239 is normally produced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-239#Production) by subjecting U-238 to neutrons. U-239 emits a beta, converting to Np-239, which also emits a beta, converting to Pu-239. Both those steps have relatively short half-lives, and chemical techniques can be used to separate the elements from one another.

Isotopes of the same element cannot be separated chemically, only physically, and the separation rate is a function of the mass ratio. Isotope separation is necessary in the [enrichment of uranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_uranium), and that process is very slow because U-238 is only slightly more massive than U-235. The separation processes almost always use [uranium hexafluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_hexafluoride) gas. Fluorine has an atomic mass of 19, so the mass ratio is around $(238 + 6×19)/(235 + 6×19)$.

Uranium hexafluoride is nasty stuff which requires very careful handling. It reacts with water (even traces of water in the atmosphere or equipment) to produce hydrofluoric acid (which is highly toxic), and of course it's radioactive.

The prime reason that Pu-239 is used is because it's a lot easier to produce (using the process mentioned earlier) than it is to enrich natural uranium.

Similar techniques to uranium enrichment can be used to separate Pu-238 and Pu-239, but the mass ratio is much worse. Here are the mass ratios, using 7 digit atomic mass numbers for the hexafluorides.

| Element | Mass ratio |
| --- | --- |
| Uranium | $1.008615$ |
| Plutonium | $1.002858$ |

In addition, [plutonium hexafluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium_hexafluoride) is even nastier than uranium hexafluoride. It's quite corrosive, and it's prone to auto-radiolysis, which means that the energy released in the radioactive decay of the plutonium has a tendency to chemically decompose it. This is especially the case with Pu-238.

[Plutonium-238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238) is an alpha emitter with a half-life of ~87.7 years. It's a preferred fuel for radiothermal generators (RTGs) because it emits a *lot* of heat, for decades. Here's a photo (courtesy of the US DOE, via Wikipedia) of a small pellet of Pu-238 dioxide, glowing from its own heat.

[image: Pu-238 dioxide pellet]

The alpha particles produced inside the pellet lose most of their kinetic energy creating heat and doing general damage. Similarly, any Pu-238 present in plutonium destined for weapons use causes damage to the crystal structure (as well as being a neutron absorber).

Of course, plutonium hexafluoride in the gaseous state doesn't trap alpha particles like a solid compound does, so it doesn't get quite as hot, but the energy from all those alphas is still a problem.

---

Your question is about plutonium in the context of a thorium reactor. It takes (at least) 7 neutrons to get from Th-232 to Pu-239. You aren't going to get much of it produced in a simple thorium reactor cycle, although some plutonium is likely to be produced in a reactor that uses [recycling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorium_fuel_cycle). However, thorium reprocessing is difficult. Some of the waste isotopes are heavy gamma emitters which can only be handled remotely. This has been a significant barrier in the commercial development of thorium-based fission power.

Comment: This is really a powerhouse of an answer. Very nicely done.

Comment: Thanks, @rob. :)

Comment: FWIW, there's some interesting info & discussion about Pu-238 & RTGs here: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50282/38535 Also see https://www.planetary.org/articles/plutonium-power-for-space-missions

Comment: @PM2Ring, agree with rob, +1 and thanks- NN

Answer (score 4):

According to [[1]](https://inldigitallibrary.inl.gov/sites/sti/sti/3667232.pdf),

> Neutron absorption in Pu-238 that does not cause fission instead
> generates Pu-239.

Let us, however. make it clear what specifically we are trying to compare. If it is Pu-238 and Pu-239, then one can use the latter in weapons directly, and the former needs to be used as a fuel in a nuclear reactor first. Not everyone uses the word "easily" for this process:-)

Comment: Pu-238 isn't used as a fuel in fission reactors because it isn't fissionable by thermal neutrons and hence it cannot sustain a chain reaction. However, it is [fertile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fertile_material), since it becomes fissionable Pu-239 when it absorbs a thermal neutron, and its alpha decay product, U-234 (which is also an alpha emitter) is also fertile. FWIW, both of those isotopes can undergo spontaneous fission (and cluster decay), but that has a *much* lower probability than alpha decay.

Comment: @PM2Ring : I did not say Pu-238 "is" used as a fuel in fission reactors, I said it "needs" to be used as a fuel to obtain Pu-239 (I guess Pu-238 is fissionable by fast neutrons). Otherwise one would need to get neutrons from some external source (say, a nuclear reactor with a different fuel). I agree that I did not mention this possibility, but it is not attractive either.

Comment: Ok, but in the context of a fission reactor the term "fuel" implies that the isotope undergoes a fission reaction, releasing energy. OTOH, I guess it's ok to refer to fertile isotopes as fuel, especially in breeder reactors, which are designed to "cook" fertile isotopes into fissile isotopes.